# How to get total count number of employee in Java?

Tags: java, getter

I have an **Employee** and **Employees** class below.
How do I go about returning Employee object at n position in the arraylist?

```
//Employee.java
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    
    public Employee (String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        
    }
```

```
//Employees.java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Employees {

    private ArrayList<Employee> employees;
    
    public Employees(){
        this.employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employees.add(new Employee("Thomas Muller","thomas.muller@uts.com"));
    }
}
```

Comment: [size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a simple `getCount()` method to fetch the total employee count:

```
public class Employees {
...
  public int getCount() {
    return this.employees.size();
  }
}
```

Later you can call this on an `Employees` instance:

```
Employees employees = new Employees();
int totalCount = employees.getCount();
System.out.println("Total count of employees:" + totalCount);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! If you don't mind, can you help me with the new question I just edit as well, very much appreciate it.